# Bootstrap prevent navbar jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know if this is a thing you can't change in bootstrap, but i want to ask you if this is maybe possible.

When i look at my page (Joomla with purity iii template) on a mobile phone, it works out good but there is a thing that does not look good.

To illustrate: X=content |      ====== navbar

This is what the page looks like on the beginning

=======

X

X

X

X

When i scroll down, the navbar disapears

X

X

X

X

When i stop scrolling, navbar jumps back to its position

=======

X

X

X

X

When i scroll up, navbar covers the content

X

X

=======

X

X

When i stop scrolling, navbar jumps back to the position

What i want to achieve is that the navbar IS ON TOP ALL THE TIME  and does not disappear or cover the content when scrolling

Here is my site: [autransfer](http://www.autransfer.at)

Comment: It looks fine to me. What browser are u using?

Comment: Works for me too on iOS.

Comment: I use the standard browser if android. does the navbar stay on top all the time in your browsers?

Comment: I cannot see any unexpected behaviours on your website. Can you share the screencast of the problem you are facing?